# Can there be entries in the hash table with the same key and same value?

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I came across hashmap recently. I am really want to know these things about hash tables. I hope this community can help me!

Can there be entries in the hash table with the same key? I think no.

Can there be entries in the hash table with the same value? I think yes, as collision is a thing in hashtable.

Can there be entries in the hash table with the same key
and same value? I dont know, maybe yes?

Comment: By definition, a hash table can have exactly one value under each key.  If two entries were to have the same hash, that would be a hash collision, and a strategy to resolve the collision would be necessary.

Comment: No, keys must be unique. There can be more than one entry with the same value, though. But this is not a collision. A collision is as Dan Farrell told you. I suggest you read about hash tables, i.e. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 0):

Keys must be unique, while values don't need to be unique. If there already is a entry in the Hashtable using the same key it'll throw an `ArgumentException`. You can use the `ContainsKey` method to check if a key is already present before adding a new value to it, if needed.

Comment: It kinda like a door then? Two doors may look the same but the keys for each door must be different?

Comment: If you want to use that metaphor I would say each door has its own unique key. The room behind the door doesn't need to be unique. Several doors could lead to identitical rooms or even to the exact same room.